# What's the easy way to test for 304 reponses?

Tags: http, caching

I need to test if my 304 responses are working, but my development environment is pretty hard set on force no-cache.

Is there an easy way to modify the max-age value of the cache-control header before it goes out?

I'm perhaps a bit optimistic in hoping chrome (or an extension, or FF) has a console command letting me alter the if-modified-since header then send the request.  Maybe paste something into a telnet connection?

Comment: Could you add a little more details on what technologies you are using?  Development and/or Hosting Enviroments, Language, etc...?

Comment: The technologies and environment are simply http, tcp/ip, etc. The test case is coming from the browsers point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/), the easy way is:

```
curl -H "If-Modified-Since: Sat, 15 May 2010 12:06:39 GMT" -i http://www.wikipedia.org | grep "HTTP/"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use tamper data - its a firefox plugin that allows you to modify request headers.
See https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/966/